# Boost.Python: Callbacks to class functions

Tags: c++, python, boost

I have an `EventManager` class written in C++ and exposed to Python. This is how I intended for it to be used from the Python side:

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        EventManager.addEventHandler(FooEvent, self.onFooEvent)
    def __del__(self):
        EventManager.removeEventHandler(FooEvent, self.onFooEvent)
    def onFooEvent(self, event):
        pass
```

(The `add-` and `remove-` are exposed as static functions of `EventManager`.)

The problem with the above code is that the callbacks are captured inside `boost::python::object` instances; when I do `self.onFooEvent` these will increase the reference count of `self`, which will prevent it from being deleted, so the destructor never gets called, so the event handlers never get removed (except at the end of the application).

The code works well for functions that don't have a `self` argument (i.e. free or static functions). How should I capture Python function objects such that I won't increase their reference count? I only need a weak reference to the objects.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `__del__` anyway. Instead, expose a regular method to remove the event handler. (Perhaps make it a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) if you see code like `x = Something(); use(x); # x should be unused from this point forward`)

Comment: @delnan But objects of classes similar to `Something` will themselves get passed to another C++ manager. When that manager no longer needs them, it deletes them. I don't think I can use context managers in this.. uhm, context.

Comment: Oh, nevermind the context manager suggestion then. Still, instead of (or rather, in addition to) deleting them to, you should just tell them to remove their event handlers. Otherwise the next patch to make memory management smarter might make your code leak.

Comment: @delnan What do you mean by 'smarter'? I want to know i what you have in mind is something that I could apply (now or at a later point). Or were you just making a general statement? :)

Comment: Any reason you can't pass in `weakref.ref(self.onFooEvent)`? Note, this may need special handling in the c++ code.

Comment: @Nathan I already tried that, and it's specifically because of the special handling that I don't want to use it. The `weakref` will get deleted and set to `None` before `__del__` is called, effectively making the call to `remove-` useless. Besides, I'd like my manager to be agnostic of Python because I'm going to be queuing events into it from both C++ and Python.

Comment: @Paul: General statment, but it may still apply to you. Finalizers aren't guaranteed to run in memory-managed languages, period. Some facts: Some GCs (including CPython's) will refuse to collect cycles of objects as it's hard to impossible to determine the intended order of the finalizers; finalizers only run (if at all) upon collection, which can be quite a while after the object becomes unreachable when you don't use refcounting or have cycles; they're explicitly not guaranteed in certain curcumstances such as interpreter shutdown; etc.

Comment: @delnan Thanks for the info. I'll be careful about that, but atm I don't see how cycles could form in my code. The owner of the object is well known (it's the other manager I mentioned).

Comment: You don't have cycle, but your object is referenced by a static object (the EventManager registration list defined in c++); A static object is garbaged collected only when application ended (as you described).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without weakref.ref(self.onFooEvent) you will never get your expected behaviour! See my  comment.